# HTML Form submission issues - blank POST data

Tags: php, html, forms

Some of our users are having trouble submitting HTML forms to PHP. These users are all from big organisations to which we have no insight as to their architecture.

When submitting the form I have been told verbally that their browser (in the example I was given it was IE11) asked them if they were happy to submit POST data when they clicked submit which I have never seen before. Upon agreeing my script keeps receiving no POST data whatsoever. This prompt is not something I have coded and so I assume it's something the organisation added via some software or extension.

I have tested IE11 successfully (and IE9 / IE10).

These users are having no difficulty submitting the same form on their mobile phones.

This is a minority of users but I am concerned that something as simple as form data is getting stripped and thus causing issues.

Any ideas, I've had 4 in the last hour and several yesterday...

Example Code:

HTML

```
<form name="survey" id="survey" method="post" action="complete.php">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); // Outputs nothing for the users with the issue and outputs the name for the users without the issue
?>
```

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Comment: It might be security settings in their internet options like 'Submit non-encrypted form data' setting to 'Prompt' or 'Disabled'. Can you post your code? Are you using SSL?

Comment: Thanks for your response - we aren't using SSL on this form but can arrange it for a later date - if these users are agreeing to the prompt it should still let the post data through though?

Comment: I can't say for sure because it seems to be an administration issue and we can't know what limitations the end-users have. SSL might help, enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in your form might also help.

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks @DimitrisFilippou

Comment: @DanieleFois I've added an example for you